# how to set binary file to null if no file has been selected

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using this code `byte[] bin = new byte[FileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength];` but the application I am designing may or may not select a file.

if user selects file the code works fine but in case if we do not want to upload any file then it gives error saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. "
if I do the following change to my code. it gives error in the insert sql statement saying no value give to the sql parameter

```
if(FileUploadSTR.HasFile)
{
    bin= new byte[FileUploadSTR.PostedFile.ContentLength];
}
else
{
    bin= null;
}
```

sql is here

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SponsorInput (SerialNumber, Requestor, Sponsor, BusinessJustification, DebugFile, DebugFileName, ProductName, SigningType, FirmwareVersion, FirmwareDescription, SmokeTestResult) 
SELECT CASE WHEN @SerialNumber = '' THEN NULL ELSE @SerialNumber END, CASE WHEN @Requestor = '' THEN NULL ELSE @Requestor END, 
    CASE WHEN @Sponsor = '' THEN NULL ELSE @Sponsor END, CASE WHEN @BusinessJustification = '' THEN NULL ELSE @BusinessJustification END, CASE WHEN @DebugFile = '' THEN NULL ELSE @DebugFile END, 
    CASE WHEN @DebugFileName = '' THEN NULL ELSE @DebugFileName END, 
    CASE WHEN @ProductName = '' THEN NULL ELSE @ProductName END, 
    CASE WHEN @SigningType = '' THEN NULL ELSE @SigningType END, 
    CASE WHEN @FirmwareVersion = '' THEN NULL ELSE @FirmwareVersion END, 
    CASE WHEN @FirmwareDescription = '' THEN NULL ELSE @FirmwareDescription END, 
    CASE WHEN @SmokeTestResult = '' THEN NULL ELSE @SmokeTestResult END", conn);
```

sql parameter is as below`

```
SqlParameter SmokeTestResult = new SqlParameter("@SmokeTestResult", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 8000);
if (bin== null)
{
    bin = new byte[0];
}
else
{
    SmokeTestResult.Value = bin;
}
command.Parameters.Add(SmokeTestResult);`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
postedFile = FileUpload.PostedFile;
byte[] bin;
if (postedFile == null)
  bin = new byte[0];
else
  bin = new byte[FileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength];
```

Comment: Upon doing so database insert query gave error."The parameterized query '(@SerialNumber nvarchar(50),@Requestor nvarchar(20),@Sponsor nva' expects the parameter '@SmokeTestResult', which was not supplied. " what could be the resolution to this

Comment: @user1144852 This means that you need to supply a value. It may not be null. Will update the answer to change that.

Comment: i tried thisSqlParameter SmokeTestResult = new SqlParameter("@SmokeTestResult", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 8000);
                if (bin == null)
                {
                    SmokeTestResult.Value = "";

                }
                else
                {
                    SmokeTestResult.Value = bin;
                } but gave error "Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Byte[]'"

Comment: @user1144852 Did you get an error with that or did it work correctly?

Comment: got error saying "Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Byte[]'"

Comment: @user1144852 Thought so, did you try the updated answer that I gave with the new byte[0]? Another option is to have 2 SQL statements, one with the parameter and the other without it.

Comment: nope it gave error "The parameterized query '(@SerialNumber nvarchar(50),@Requestor nvarchar(20),@Sponsor nva' expects the parameter '@SmokeTestResult', which was not supplied. "

Comment: @user1144852 Please update your question to include the full block of code and then we will be able to correct it for you. This should include the SQL and the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest just to check if FileUpload.PostedFile== null and not do anything that requires it

Comment: Upon doing so database insert query gave error."The parameterized query '(@SerialNumber nvarchar(50),@Requestor nvarchar(20),@Sponsor nva' expects the parameter '@SmokeTestResult', which was not supplied. " what could be the resolution to this

Comment: Are those values based on the PostedFile?

Comment: no they are not based on the posted files posted file is totally different attribute here. in some cases it can be null but the scenario with null value is making trouble

Comment: Any way you can post the relevant code in the question?